# Why CascadeType.MERGE delete records in database

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript, hibernate

I am developping a web application of REST type with Angular (Typescript) for the frontend, and Spring (boot, rest, data, hibernate) for the backend which is connected to a MySQL database.
In this application, a User java Object has attributes and is linked to severals lists of objects (publications, intendedUsages, roles, userGroups and managedGroups), using JPA annotation like you can see below.

In the User.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "userId")
private Long userId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String photo;
private String instantMessaging;
@Column(length = 50)
private String phoneNumber;
private String personnalURL;
private Timestamp charterAcceptanceDate;

@Column(unique=true)
private String username;
private Timestamp expirationDate;
private String password;
private Timestamp creationDate;
private Timestamp approvedDate;
private boolean isActive;
private boolean isAdmin;


// Relations
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Publication> publications = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<IntendedUsage> intendedUsages = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

// List of groups the user belongs to.
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
name = "user_group", 
joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, 
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "group_id") }
)
private List<Group> userGroups = new ArrayList<>();

// List of groups managed by the user.
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
    name = "managed_group", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "group_id") }
)
private List<Group> managedGroups = new ArrayList<>();


In Role.java

@JsonSerialize(using = UserListCustomSerializer.class)
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();



In Group.java

// List of users included in the group.
@JsonSerialize(using = UserListForGroupCustomSerializer.class)
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userGroups")
private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

// List of users who are managing the group.
@JsonSerialize(using = ManagerListForGroupCustomSerializer.class)
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "managedGroups")
private List<User> managerUsers = new ArrayList<>();
```

In the frontend, I have a form to modify User characteristics. When I submit modifications, the frontend sends to the backend a JSON file like this :

```
{
"active":true,
"admin":false,
"approvedDate":"1970-01-01T23:47:13.000+0000",
"charterAcceptanceDate":"1970-01-09T18:44:13.000+0000",
"creationDate":"1970-01-02T10:49:26.000+0000",
"email":"jack.bauer@gmake.com",
"expirationDate":"1970-01-02T10:49:26.000+0000",
"firstName":"Jack",
"instantMessaging":"skype.com",
"lastName":"Bauer",
"login":"","password":"",
"personnalURL":"http://www.jack.com",
"phoneNumber":"0686596352",
"photo":"/home/jjj/",
"userId":1,
"username":"jbauerooooo"
}
```

There is no information about the User publications, intendedUsages, roles, userGroups and managedGroups, which is normal. 
Here I just want to modify general characteristics of the user, not his lists.

I thought that with CascadeType.MERGE, if there is no information about Lists linked with the User, existing lists (recorded in the database) will stay in the database.

This is true for OneToMany relations but NOT for ManyToMany relations. The current data record in the database for roles, userGroups, managedGroups are deleted when the frontend sends the JSON file above.

Why ?
How to avoid this ?

I tried to use CascadeType.ALL and in that case, all data concerning lists are deleted.
I tried all values of CascadeType for ManyToMany relations. Its is the same problem.

Thanks in advance for your answer...

Answer (score 0):

Merge doesn't do what you think it does. Its fairly complicated and I wouldn't be able to explain what it does well but you can look it up and should find some decent articles. When you send that json data is is serialized and even if you didn't include it in the json file java will have the not included fields as null. When you save the entity hibernate will delete children or set fields as null (because in java they are null). To accomplish your goal I would use the @DynamicUpdate annotation on your entity. Then you could create a DTO that represents your partial json data. Then in your service fetch the entity by id and set its relevant fields from the DTO. Lazy loading will ensure that children aren't pulled from the database and the @DynamicUpdate will ensure that only the updated fields are included in the update SQL statement coming from hibernate. This should be fairly efficient. I would also suggest setting the hibernate.show_sql flag in your properties to true so you can see what hibernate is doing under the hood. Hibernate can do some funky stuff or even ignore your annotations sometimes.

Comment: Hello Matt, thank you very much for your answer. I studied it very attentively. My problem is that I'm quiet a newbie to Angular, Spring and REST applications.
So I had tried to learn how to build a DTO, but it will take a long time, and I'm short in time. So, temporaly, I made the choice to postpone a full form from the frontend to the backend and it works with cascade = CascadeType.ALL on the User lists.
I know it's not an optimal solution. But I keep in mind your solution and as soon as I will have time, I will try it.
Thanks again.